# Proxy mTLS authentication to upstream

Tags: ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, mtls

I have webservice with several clients which authenticate with client certificate. Now I need to put some sort of proxy between the clients and service and forward their request to original service, while preserving their authentication. I DO have their certificates and keys, so it should be possible, but I looked at Apache and nginx, but they only allow configuring one client certificate for upstream. What I need  is to select dynamically which certificate to use based on original client.

I pretty much don't care if it's Apache, nginx, envoy or something complete different.

I looked at Apache and nginx documentation, but it seems they do not supporr such usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge as you. You can do multiple mTLS "connections" via multiple Proxy entries in Apache 2.4 onwards.

However, as you can see in my latest post, this can be very finicky and hard to debug.